# Prompt Save dialog box while downloading blob from azure storage

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have an ASP.NET web application to download  blobs from my azure storage. When I use blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream); it automatically downloads it to the project location when run the web aplication in local machine. But if I want to deploy this web aplication in cloud, How can I get a dialog box to save the blobs to be dowloaded ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you could do:

1. Set the `content-type` property of the blob to `application/octet-stream` or don't set the content type of the blob at all. While this approach may work in most of the browsers but not in all. IE is quite smart about this would actually try to read the file type from the file stream and decides if to display the file in the browser or to prompt "Save As".
2. Download the blob first on your web server and then serve that file by setting the `Content Disposition` response header value to something like `attachment; filename="Your file name"'.